# How can't show if service running test green

Tags: java, junit

I have 5 services in `file.bat` 3 running and 2 stopped. I want to have 3 success green test and 2 red

I think the problem is with my var `ligne`

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class Cmd {

  static String       a      = null;
  static String       ligne  = "";
  public final String output = null;

  static String       CHEMIN = "vvvvvvvvvv";

  private static BufferedReader getOutput(Process p)
  {
    return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
  }

  private static BufferedReader getError(Process p)
  {
    return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
  }

  static public String Stateprocess()
  {
    if (ligne.contains("RUNNING")) {
      a = "RUNNING";
      System.out.println("ok");
    } else {
      a = "STOPPED";
      System.out.println("no");
    }

    return a;
  }


  public boolean ping(String CHEMIN)
  {

    int exitValue = 1;

    try {

      String[] commande = {"cmd.exe", "/C", CHEMIN + "test-sc.bat"};
      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime()
                         .exec(commande);
      BufferedReader output = getOutput(p);
      BufferedReader error = getError(p);


      while ((ligne = output.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(ligne);
        // System.out.println(ligne.contains("STOPPED"));
      }

      while ((ligne = error.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(ligne);
      }

      exitValue = p.waitFor();

    }


    catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return exitValue == 0;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Cmd exemple = new Cmd();
    boolean trouve = exemple.ping(CHEMIN);
    System.out.println(trouve);
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what are you asking. Please elaborate more.

Answer (score 0):

This code stay reading from out and err streams until the end of the streams has been reached. But this will let your java code to wait till the process has completed its task.

So if this is what you want, I suggest to move the statement

```
  exitValue = p.waitFor();
```

before the two while loops where you read the streams.

This should let you to be sure that both the streams are written completely.